# Is it possible to set the pre-change value of an input element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an input element with an `onchange` event. The `onchange` event alerts the user if the value is not accepted, and returns focus back to the input element.

However, if the user then clicks out of the element, the `onchange` event doesn't fire - which is understandable since the user hasn't made a further change, but it introduces the problem of only validating once.

I explored a possible solution to reset the value back to what it was before it was changed, but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible for the sake of allowing the user to correct the value they entered without having to type the whole thing again.

Another possibility was to put the validation into the blur event but this would introduce other problems such as events on other elements firing if they are focused.

So my question is, if the user changes the input value from 'X' to 'Y', can I return focus to the element, leaving the value as 'Y' but make it treat 'X' as the pre-change value, thus behaving so if the user changes it back to 'X' the change event will not subsequently fire, but if they leave it as 'Y' and lose focus again, the change event fires again as if changing from 'X' to 'Y'?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just mark the field as invalid (using CSS or jQuery to add markup) instead of using an alert? The field remains invalid until the user changes the value to a valid one, and the validation script removes the invalid marking.

Comment: Whether I use CSS, jQuery or an alert isn't really the issue or cause of the problem. The issue is, I have to return the focus back to the element, and unfortunately this means that a subsequent change event will be based on the 'new' value rather than the original one.

Comment: User gives form element focus. User changes value. Value is invalid, and is marked as such, **without form element losing focus**. User changes value again. Value is checked as valid and invalid marking is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Is the input type text? In these circumstances I prefer to use onkeyup instead of onchange for the very reason you're describing.

Sometimes even that doesn't work: This will not capture the change when text is pasted into the text box using a mouse since a key isn't pressed (but shift+insert or ctrl+v are). You might want to add the same event to both onchange and onkeyup to cover all bases.

Comment: It is a type text, and it accepts numeric values only (using a combination of onkeyup and onkeypress to suppress invalid characters). That isn't the issue. My scenario is, if I want to add an onchange event to check that the finally typed number is between a minimum and maximum value (which I obviously can't use onkeyup for) I need to use onchange, and the issue is as described, i.e. the onchange will fire the first time, putting the focus back in to the element, but then won't fire again if the user then simply clicks/tabs out again.

Comment: Is this part of a form that might be submitted? If so, this is what i'd do: Use the onkeyup event to style the text box (as suggested in the answer by Tim) or insert/remove a message after the text box. Use a separate event attached to the forms onsubmit event that blocks the form submission and alerts the user if they ignored the warning. Is that a plausible solution to your problem?

Comment: Having re-read your question, is it the case that you do not want the text box to be left with an invalid value at any stage?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's a self-validating custom control.